# Force docusign for making an API call to client server

Tags: api, docusignapi

Is it possible to force docusign for making an API call to client server.

For example, If any template / document changed it will make an API call to let say exmple.com with relevant data and message.

One more example, If Client has requested some document for sign, When all the signer get signed or any signer get signed it should make API call to client website that such things is done on docusign.

Also request you provide an alternate way, Our technology is PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If Client has requested some document for sign, When
>   all the signer get signed or any signer get signed it should make API
>   call to client website that such things is done on docusign.

This is possible using the [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com.au/developer-center/explore/connect) service. This service can be configured to make a SOAP call or HTTP Post to a client endpoint upon an event occuring such as envelope completion (other events are possible too).

> If any template / document changed it will make an API call to let say
>   exmple.com with relevant data and message.

To my knowledge this is not possible today with DocuSign.